# Android Best Practice In Navigating To Another Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

Is It better to call on finish(); before calling intent to navigate to another activity, or just call the intent. also note if up navigation is used which way is better

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to close the current Activity and start new Activity you  need to call `finish()`.

But whenever you don't need to close current activity and start new one. Then you don't need to call finish().

When you don't call `finish()`. you can access the same activity back from new Activity.

I don't think one is better and other not. We can use both for based on our needs.

Note : If you don't call finish() then you don't need to create Activity again. Back from new activity. So it is faster.

Comment: by not creating the activity again, you mean not having to call start activity on back?

Comment: Yes you don't need to use intent. Just finish() the new one and it will back.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends on what you want the user experience to be. The default is that the `Activity`s are left on the backstack in the order the user navigated them. So when he presses back, he returns to the previous `Activity`. And if he presses the HOME button and restarts the app again later, the app begins with the same `Activity` where he had left off. Calling `finish()` for each `Activity` will subvert this behavior.

You can customize the backstack & history behavior in a wide variety of ways. Take a look at the following links:

**1.** [**Activity tags in App Manifest**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html). ([`launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) is of particular interest here).

**2.** [**Tasks and Back Stack**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Comment: @user1950784: although I think that my answer is better than that of `Amsheer` :)

Comment: i saw the answer before that's why man but i did upvote you:p

Comment: @user1950784: this answer should be marked correct. It is more relevant and provides more useful information than Amsheer's answer .... :)

Answer (score 1):

> also note if up navigation is used which way is better

Although the Amsheer answer is good one but I want to add on your above stated statement and that is YES. If you are using Up navigation it is more convenient from the point of view of user experience. you can set up navigation drawer and move from fragment to fragment which looks more great then going from activity to activity.

Keep it in mind that I am talking about user perspective I am not saying that moving from one activity to another is bad. But it looks great from navigating from one fragment to another using navigation drawer.